# Find the position of a value in an array

Tags: c#

I have this code to find the position of a certain value within my array:

```
int position = Array.IndexOf<double>(myarray, 0.03);
```

is there a way to get it to work so that it gives me the position of a value that is less than certain value? for example I want the position of the first occurrence of a value less than 0.04

Comment: using `Linq` you can get all values below, equal, larger, etc ... for example: http://screencast.com/t/Y5sSVZOP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Array.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.findindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by a specified predicate, and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within an Array or a portion of it.

```
int position = Array.FindIndex(myarray, n => n < 0.04)
```

Comment: I didn't know that method. That's better than LINQ.

Comment: It yield position = 0, but when I do:
int position = Array.FindIndex(myarray, n => n > 0.04)
it gives the right position of value > 0.04

Comment: if `position` is 0 that would suggest that first element of your array if less then 0.04. If you do `n > 0.04` it will find index of first element that is greater then 0.04 as it _searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by a specified predicate_

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ:

```
int position = myArray.Select((v, index) => new { v, index })
                      .First(x => x.v < 0.03)
                      .index;
```

it will throw an exception when no elements match your condition.

To get a default value instead of exception, use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var item = myArray.Select((v, index) => new { v, index })
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.v < 0.03);
var position = item == null ? -1 : item.index;
```